# how to make a button move when the size of an input increases

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have a page like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="peet.png"/> <title>Surge</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="desktop">
           <div class="headermenu"> 
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div align="left">
               <div class="logo" style=" font-size: 39px;">Surge</div>
                </div><div class="search_box"><form method="get" action="/search/search.php" id="search"><input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." /><button class="attach" type="submit"><img src="search.png" width="35px" height="35px"/></button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css looks like this:

```
*{
    font-family: Comic Sans Ms;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

body{
   background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.headermenu{
    background-color: #00b9ed;
    height: 67px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid gray; 
}

#wrapper{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;

}

.logo{
    width: 125px;
    font-family: Lucida Handwriting;
}

.search_box input{
    background-color: #00b9ed;
    outline: none !important;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    margin-left: 190px;
    width: 300px;
}
#search input[type=text]{
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
     text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease 0s;
     -moz-transition:all 0.7s ease 0s;
     -o-transition:all 0.7s ease 0s;
     transition:all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
#search input[type=text]:focus{
    background-color:  rgb(46,122,237);
    color: white;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.9) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.9) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.9) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.attach{
    position: absolute;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
    top: 13px;
    margin-left: 490px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: #00b9ed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.attach{
    margin-left: 590px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 959px) {
 .desktop {
 display: block;
 }
 .mobile {
 display: none;
 }

}@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
 .desktop {
 display: none;
 }
 .mobile {
 display: block;
 }
}
```

According to the code when the search bar is not focused on the width is 300px (i would have loved to put an image but stack overflow is not allowing me) and there is a search button attached by the right

but when the search bar is focused on the length increases to 400px (i did that purposely)

Now what i want is that when search bar is focused on the search button will still be attached but instead the button stays stagnant and the input passes through the back
PLease explain as simple as you can (i'm a noob)

check the pics below for more understanding

[This is the page when the search bar is not focused on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0GaN.png)

[this is the page when focused on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm9JJ.png)

as you can see it is a huge mess when it is focused on
Again What i want is that when the search bar is focused on the search icon should be pushed

sorry for it being so long

> © Copyright 2020 Coolcat

Comment: have a look here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animated_search.asp this will help.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal sorry but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

this should help you with your query.

```
 <form action="/action_page.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

button {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  input[type=text],
  button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }

  input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `#search input[type=text]` add

```
#search input[type=text] {
  position: relative; //+
  top: -30px; //+
```

Remove all this code :

```
.attach{ 
    position: absolute;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
    top: 13px;
    margin-left: 490px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: #00b9ed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.attach{ 
    margin-left: 590px; 
}
```

and Replace it with :

```
.attach{
    position: absolute;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
    top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: #00b9ed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image: Before focusing on your input]
[image: After focusing on your input]

Answer (score 0):

I have adjusted your HTML and you CSS to achieve what you want.

Just so you know, what you need should never be done. It makes you page not pass the WCAG validations because it renders part of the content of the search text box inaccessible when it's hidden by the button.

I have removed things that didn't make sense in your CSS. For example, paddings cannot be set to `auto`. It's an actual error to use it. And also, you should avoid using the value `0px` for anything. Zero is just zero. Write something like `margin: 0;` instead of `margin: 0px;`

And, avoid using absolute positioning. Use it only when it can't be avoided.

Checkout the attached code snippet to see if it's doing what you need.

```css
    * {
        font-family: Comic Sans Ms;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    body {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }

    .headermenu {
        background-color: #00b9ed;
        height: 67px;
        border-bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 0.5px solid gray;
    }

    #wrapper {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .logo {
        width: 125px;
        font-family: Lucida Handwriting;
    }

    .search_box input {
        background-color: #00b9ed;
        outline: none !important;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-left: 190px;
        width: 300px;
    }

    #search input[type=text] {
        padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
        text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
        transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    }

    #search input[type=text]:focus {
        background-color: rgb(46, 122, 237);
        color: white;
        width: 400px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
        text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .attach {
        outline: none !important;
        border: none;
        height: 38px;
        background-color: #00b9ed;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        position: fixed;
        left: 615px;
    }

    @media all and (max-width: 959px) {
        .desktop {
            display: block;
        }

        .mobile {
            display: none;
        }

    }

    @media all and (max-width: 479px) {
        .desktop {
            display: none;
        }

        .mobile {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    .row {
        display: table-row;
    }

    .col {
        display: table-cell;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="peet.png"/>
        <title>Surge</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="desktop">
        <div class="headermenu">
            <div id="wrapper" class="row">
                <div align="left" class="col">
                    <div class="logo" style="font-size: 39px;">Surge</div>
                </div>
                <div class="search_box col">
                    <form method="get" action="/search/search.php" id="search">
                        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..."/>
                        <button class="attach" type="submit"><img src="search.png" width="35px" height="35px"/></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```